# Find Foreign Keys from a T4 Template generator

Tags: visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, t4, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to generate a method for each of my Foreign Keys in my Entities to return a list of records based on that foreign key. I know of a way of determining the Primary Key:

```
foreach (var edmProperty in simpleProperties)
{
    bool isPrimaryKey = ef.IsKey(edmProperty);
    if(isPrimaryKey)
    {
       //do stuff
    }
}
```

Is there a way of finding the Foreign Keys?
I am using EF 6 with Visual Studio 2013.
Thanks

Comment: "return a list of records" ... That's what collection navigation properties are for. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Let's say I have a product. My product has a categoryID as a foreign key. I would like to generate a method with my T4 template to return all products with a given categoryID. As I'm cycling through all of my properties in the T4 template for my entity, how can I tell which property is a foreign key so I can create this method. I can figure out which is a Primary key but not a foreign key.

Comment: Why a method? And in which class? `Category` will have a navigation property `Products`.

Comment: I would like to add a method to the generated code so that I don't have my context in the codebehind. This will be for all classes in my model that are generated from Entity Framework (database first model). I guess I can get it from the Category class but then I will have to create a custom method like ctx.Categories.Include("Products").ToList() if I want the products returned. Either that or have the context in my codebehind so that the Products will automatically be loaded when I access the Category.

Comment: Why don't you show an example of what such a method should look like? It's still not clear to me, mainly because you never tell where these methods should belong and how they should operate.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. For many reasons:

- It breaks persistence ignorance. POCO's are not supposed to know anything about the data layer. You may even have POCOs defined in a separate assembly that has no reference to EF.
- Methods like `GetByCountryID` are typically repository methods, they don't belong to an entity class.
- Static methods shouldn't be scattered over a class model. They're typical for utility classes or factories (it could make sense to have a method like `City.New()`).
- How would you know that `City` has a `GetByCountryID` method? There may even be more classes having the same method.
- The object(s) obtained by the method are in no way related to a `City` instance, but its location seems to intend such an association.
- If you remove the property `Country` from the EDMX (e.g. because it's never used), the method also disappears.
- **The main reason**: there is no substitute for navigation properties. If you want to get `Categories` *and* their `Products` you have to load them in a way that EF knows how to associate them. You either do this by `Include`, or by including them in a projection, or by lazy loading, or by fetching the `Products` later, but all **in the same context**. Your proposed methods can only produce dissociated entities, and disconnected too (i.e. not attached to a context).

There are other patterns to hide data layer details from other application layers, for instance repositories with dependency injection.

Comment: I see what you mean...but doesn't having your context in your codebehind a bad idea because of it being tied to your UI? I guess that's where your suggestion of repositories and dependency injection would come in...not too familiar with that pattern.

Comment: Why would the context be tied to the UI if your entities have no reference to it? If, for instance, you have a service layer that returns entities, nobody outside the service needs to know about EF.

Comment: When you say "you have a service layer that returns entities, nobody outside the service needs to know about EF"...do I need another layer on top of what my T4 Templates are generating? I was thinking that the methods (generated by the T4 template) that interact with my Entities and return objects to my UI is my service layer.
If I put:
using(MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
{
  //do stuff with my context
}
...in my codebehind, then my UI is directly tied to the data layer. I apologize if I'm not following.

Comment: Yes, in that case the UI has a reference to EF. That's not necessarily bad, but usually you will create a service layer in a separate assembly, in which there may be classes like `ProductService` having methods like `GetProducts(some specification)`, or `CreateProduct(some other specification, or a Product entity)`. These services may communicate with EF directly or through repositories, although I'm not a fan of the latter.

Comment: Thanks Gert. I see what you're saying. The result that I was trying to achieve was to create these GetProducts() and CreateProduct() methods through my T4 template but I should probably leave my generated code as is and add another layer for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I get the Foreign Key Property name.

```
public IEnumerable<NavigationProperty> GetParentNavigationProperties(EntityType type)
{
    return type.NavigationProperties.Where(np => np.DeclaringType == type && np.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity != RelationshipMultiplicity.Many);
}
```